# XML and XSL files

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got 4 different XML files which I want to join to make one file. How can I do that?

Each file contains a parent and at least 4 children. Parents are called `genre 1,2,3,4` and the children are artist, name, etc. Each file is shown in an HTML table.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more detail if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Do you want to do this with some XML parser or ?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: xml for the sorce code and then xsl for the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

Use the XSL document() function.

```
$d1 = document('doc1.xml'), document('doc2.xml'), ...
```

The comma's combine the loaded elements into a single sequence (at least in XSL 2, not sure about 1).

If you want the sequence of items within the genre tags use:

```
$d1 = document('doc1.xml')/genre, document('doc2.xml')/genre, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT template will do exactly what you've said you want done:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <output>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('file1.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('file3.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('file4.xml')"/>
   </output>
</xsl:template>
```

If this isn't the right answer, add some more detail to your question.